# JSON jQuery auto-fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

first of all, I really haven't learn any javascript at all, and I am stuck here.

[image: code for auto-fill input that I got from a friend.]

I want to get these `link` in this JSON example.

```
"list": [
    [
      "List of recipes",
      [
        {
          "name": "Eggs",
          "links": [
            {
              "method": "Fry",
              "link": "https://example.com/category/fry"
            },
          ]
        },
      ]
    ]
```

I can't elaborate with my friend's example code, can anyone help me?

Comment: You want the links array? Note: that's not valid JSON.

Comment: "I really haven't learn any javascript at all" that would be the reason you're stuck. Starting with a complex task when you can't perform a simple one isn't going to end well. I'd say, go take a JS basics / programming basics course. For example this one on Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your JSON isn't valid so you need to fix that first.
2. When it's valid parse it with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).
3. When it's parsed you'll have a nested array data structure. You need to access the links array by navigating through the tree with the array indexes.

---

```
// Returns an array
data.list[0]

// Get the second element of that array
// (the first element is the text "List of recipes")
// which is also an array
data.list[0][1]

// Access the first element of that array
// (an object) and return the links array
data.list[0][1][0].links
```

```js
const json = '{"list":[["List of recipes",[{"name":"Eggs","links":[{"method":"Fry","link":"https://example.com/category/fry"}]}]]]}';

const data = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(data.list[0][1][0].links);
```